# Why is this regex matching?

Tags: c#, regex

Good afternoon! I've tried to write a pattern that matches only when a string contains a date in a given format, or either of two matching phrases:

```
(?=(?<p0>(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[ ](\d+)(,)[ ](\d+)[ ](\d+):(\d+):(\d+) (PM|AM)))?(?=(?<p1>MATCHINGPHRASE2))?(?=(?<p2>MATCHINGPHRASE3))?
```

I have a method that calls the regex that uses this pattern like this:

```
internal bool IsSubjectRecognized(string subject)
    {
        var match = _regEx.Match(subject);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Finally, I have a unit test, to ensure that the above method will return false for strings that don't contain the date, or either match phrase that looks like this:

```
public void IsSubjectRecognizedRejectsReggoStrings()
    {
        var subject = "Watch out for the medalions. My diamonds are wreckless.";
        var rules = new MatchingRules();
        Assert.IsFalse(rules.IsSubjectRecognized(subject));
    }
```

Why does this return true?!

Comment: Assuming the `{` and `}` aren't actually part of the pattern, everything in the regex pattern is optional (followed by a `?`), so the pattern matches every string.

Comment: If you have trouble deciphering/understanding your regular expression, you can visualize its logic with the help of a service like https://www.debuggex.com/ (make sure you choose PCRE as regex flavour)

Comment: @elgonzo Neat! Thanks man!

Comment: All of the major groups in your pattern are quantified with `?` so it will match the zero-length positions at the beginning of the string, the end of the string, and in between each character.

Answer (score 0):

Let's unwrap that regex as if using perl's `/x` modifier (I've converted spaces to `\x20` since `/x` skips over spaces and comments):

```
(?=
  (?<p0>
    (Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)
    [\x20]
    (\d+)
    (,)
    [\x20]
    (\d+)
    [\x20]
    (\d+):(\d+):(\d+)\x20(PM|AM)
  )
)?
(?=
  (?<p1>MATCHINGPHRASE2)
)?
(?=
  (?<p2>MATCHINGPHRASE3)
)?
```

Let's simplify that to see what is happening at the outer levels:

```
(?= (?<p0>DATEREGEX) )?
(?= (?<p1>MATCHINGPHRASE2) )?
(?= (?<p2>MATCHINGPHRASE3) )?
```

This creates three **optional** zero-width forward lookaheads, so it should match anything.

Consider (using perl because it's easy to demonstrate on the command line):

```
$ echo foo |perl -ne 'print if /(?=nope)?/'
foo
```

If `foo` matches `(?=nope)?` then it should be printed.  It's printed, so there was a match.

Forward lookaheads are typically used for skipping ahead to ensure something is present.  I don't think you're looking to do that here, but without some sample text of what should and should not match, I can't be sure.

You probably just want something like this:

```
(?<p0>
  (Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)
  [\x20]
  (\d+)
  (,)
  [\x20]
  (\d+)
  [\x20]
  (\d+):(\d+):(\d+)\x20(PM|AM)
)
(?<p1>MATCHINGPHRASE2)
(?<p2>MATCHINGPHRASE3)
```

or, all collapsed again:

```
(?<p0>(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) (\d+)(,) (\d+) (\d+):(\d+):(\d+)\x20(PM|AM))(?<p1>MATCHINGPHRASE2)(?<p2>MATCHINGPHRASE3)
```

(You also don't need those character classes;   (and `\x20` and `[\x20]`) are identical to `[ ]` unless there was a paste issue and there's something I'm missing in that class.  Instead, you probably want `\s` or `[[:space:]]` so that you can cover all white-space characters, but I'll leave that up to you.)

See also:

- [Regex101 explanation of your original regex](https://regex101.com/r/RsziX2/1)
- [Regex101 explanation of my proposed regex](https://regex101.com/r/NZTl1D/1)